# Change the position (size) of each application in python

Tags: python

I'm writing a program that should resize the Mozilla Firefox screen to (1200 x 500).
I put the sample code that does this , but the program is minimized.
Please help solve this problem

```
import win32gui

def enumHandler(hwnd, lParam):
    if win32gui.IsWindowVisible(hwnd):
        if 'Mozilla Firefox' in win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd):
            win32gui.MoveWindow(hwnd, -5, 0, 500, 1200, True) # x,y,with,height

win32gui.EnumWindows(enumHandler, None)
```